# Push more than 3 ViewController in NavigationController from AppDelegate App crash

Tags: ios, push-notification, xamarin.ios, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I am working on Push Notification. Now When the Application is raise to Device and When I Tap on it. I want to push 3 ViewController to Navigation Stack.

So I am using below code to do this.

**AppDelegate.cs** Code

```
Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();

var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
var webController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("DashBoardViewController") as DashBoardViewController;

Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController(webController, Menu);
Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController(new DummyControllerLeft(), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = false };

Window.RootViewController = Menu;
Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

var storyboarddd = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
var webControllerdd = storyboarddd.InstantiateViewController("DashBoardViewController") as DashBoardViewController;
webControllerdd.reloadNotication();

UINavigationController nav = webController.NavigationController;
var notifyWebController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("NotificationListViewController") as NotificationListViewController;
notifyWebController.navigationContoller = nav;
nav.PushViewController(notifyWebController, true);

if (type.Equals("Damage Report"))
{
    var webController2 = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("DamageReportViewController") as DamageReportViewController;
    webController2.DamageReportId = id;
    webController2.navigationContoller = nav;
    nav.PushViewController(webController2, true);
}
if (type.Equals("Overloss"))
{
    var webController2 = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("OverlossViewController") as OverlossViewController;
    webController2.PacketId = id;
    webController2.navigationContoller = nav;
    nav.PushViewController(webController2, true);
}
```

The upper code is working fine to open Specific ViewController.

But My App crash after it with the crash Log.

**Crash Report :**

```
2017-07-26 15:25:18.330 Aastha.iOS[6357:2021514] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2017-07-26 15:25:18.740 Aastha.iOS[6357:2021514] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

**My Solution :**

When i search on google and SO someone says that Open ViewController one after another from each ViewController `ViewDidAppear` method but I am not sure If this is correct way.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: Try to push all controller after some kind of delay. It might not crash the app.

Comment: Posted an answer but deleted it (didn't notice it's for xamarin). Having said that... `UINavigationController` includes a method for establishing multiple controllers as children (`func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController], animated: Bool)`). I know nothing about xamarin but maybe the method is bridged there as well (?)

Comment: Just checked Xamarin's documentation... The method [exists for sure](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UINavigationController.SetViewControllers/p/UIKit.UIViewController[]/System.Boolean/). So you need something like `nav.SetViewControllers([controllers], true)`

Comment: @Alladinian check Lope answer if I push Viewcontroller without Animation is open All Viewcontroller but After that it crash without crash log.

Comment: @Ironman Sorry but I don't understand... Lope's answer uses an entirely different approach... If you want to add multiple children controllers to your navigation stack `SetViewControllers` is the way to go...

Comment: @Alladinian can you post with some code with delay option to SetViewController.

Comment: @Ironman Would be glad to, but as I said, I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but I do have some experience with iOS. So I guess it would be trivial for someone that has more experience in Xamarin (and can test it) to post an answer here

Comment: @Alladinian can you say how much time after I have to set the Next ViewController..So it won't crash.

Comment: @Ironman You don't... that's the point, you set a _list_ of controllers all at once and pass `true` for the second parameter to enable animation. Have you checked the documentation I have linked on my comments above?

Comment: @Alladinian I want to disable animation sorry from my question it is set true. but 3 ViewController push one after one that's why my app is get crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't push more than one view controller with animation. If you want user to see transtions A -> B -> C you indeed have to do it in A's and B's viewDidAppear method.

If you want user to only see the last view controller C and be able to go back through A and B, you can push them all at once, but you need to do it without animation:

```
nav.PushViewController(webController2, false);
```

Another option is to use SetViewControllers like this:

```
nav.SetViewControllers([A, B, C], true);
```

this will push all 3 view controllers at the same time and only the topmost one will be animated using push transition. I don't think this fits your situation, just adding it here for completeness sake.

Comment: well I try your solution.

Comment: open all ViewController is fine But Now it also Crash without crash report.

Comment: If it is crashing even without animation, the problem might be somewhere else. Do you still get warnings the console?

Comment: No Now the warning is gone but still crash the App.

Comment: sorry, I can't help you further. I have no idea what debugging options xamarin offers

Comment: After Restart Xamarin Studio and Clean and Rebuild is work for me.